Jest Unit test for nested function javascript
How do I write a unit test for nested functions? I tried to reach the reject value with the test below but the test is failing. The output of the failed message does say there is an error and the test below increases the test coverage. Should I not catch the err?
import access from './access'


describe("Access", () => {
it('should handle the error', async() => {

   await access.register().catch((err) => {
    expect(err.message).toBe("There was an error")
   }
  })
}


This is the file I am trying to test with a nested function. The request function is within the return value if the promise is rejected.
access.js file



let allow = ''
const register = () => {
     if (allow === '') {

      return (allow = new Promise(function(reject, resolve){
        const auth = {
           method: 'POST',
           headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json'
           },
           json: true
        }


      request(auth, function(err, resp){
        if (err) {
           reject({message:"There was an error"})
        }else{
         
            if(resp.statusCode === 400){
              const err = '400 Error'
               reject({message: err.message})

              } else{
                resolve({message: 'Success'})
              } 
        }
      });

    }));
      }else{
      console.log('you are allowed')
      return allow;
    }
    
};


module.exports = {register};


Please give a [mre]. What you've posted has basic syntax errors, and you appear to be mixing up CommonJS (module.exports) and ESM (import).

fixed the syntax errors

No, you haven't.

Testing nested functions can be tricky and highly implementation-specific. IMO  better approach is to focus on testing the functionality. Here’s how:

Trigger the Action: Invoke the function that calls the nested function you want to test.
Mock the Call: Use a mocking library to intercept the call.
Simulate Errors: Throw an error using the mock.
Verify the Outcome: Ensure the error is properly returned or displayed in the UI. This method ensures you are testing the end-to-end behavior rather than the implementation details.

Each approach has its pros and cons, but generally, it’s better to test functionality. This aligns with the principle of testing behavior over implementation, making your tests more resilient to changes and ensuring they reflect the user’s perspective. However, for critical or complex logic, unit tests for specific functions can complement functional tests effectively.

I agree with testing functionality. I want to test the reject condition but triggering the function that provide the error message is where I'm having the issue.
